# Combining two event handlers, jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two events that I want to observe on an object,

```
input.blur(function(event) {
  ajaxSubmit(this);
  event.preventDefault();
});

form.submit(function(event) {
  ajaxSubmit(this);
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

But I feel like this isn't dry enough, can I bind two events to my object `input` and execute my function `ajaxSubmit()` if either fire?

---

What would be super cool is if you could do:

```
input.bind("blur", "submit", function(event) {
  ajaxSubmit(this);
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: You speak of "an object", but your sample references two objects (`input` and `form`).

Comment: yah... I didnt really make any sense there huh. but what if they were the same object? and the events made sense, like "hover" and "blur" or something? is there a simpler way to bind multiple events?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method

```
$("#yourinput").on("blur submit", functionname);
```

Can combine any number of events; separate them with a space.

Comment: Of course this would not work since input fields do not have `submit` events, but the concept is sound for binding multiple events.

Comment: He can wire any events inside the bind function.

Comment: @adamantium, sorry I was unclear. The code would not throw an error, but the `submit` event would not be called on `form` submit as seems to be the OP's intention.

Comment: Hey you actually answered my question, even though I asked it like a dork and it didn’t even make any sense, thanks guys!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, just declare the function and then bind it to the events:

```
var ajaxCallback = function(event){
  ajaxSubmit(this);
  event.preventDefault();
};

input.blur(ajaxCallback);
form.submit(ajaxCallback);
```

*Note about variable declaration:*

As @cletus points out, the way I declare the function provides a variable that is private to whichever scope it is defined in. I always program this way to minimize polluting the global namespace. However, if you are **not** defining both this callback *and* binding it to the elements in the same block of code, you should define it this way:

```
function ajaxCallback(event){ ... }
```

That way it is available wherever you later bind it using the `.blur` and `.submit` methods.

Comment: You're better off defining the function: function ajaxCallback() { ... }. Your way could have the variable undefined when you try and use it whereas a straight function definition doesn't have that problem.

Comment: @cletus I wrote it that way intentionally, but you have a good point that the difference may not immediately be apparent to those reading my answer. I updated it to provide some explanation around the options of declaring the function. Thanks!

Comment: @Doug Neiner: You bound the handler *after* the function expression, so your code is fine. Both expressions define the function in whatever scope the code is in.

Comment: @Crescent Fresh, The difference could cause a problem if the function declaration and the binding calls were in separate `$(function(){ ... })` blocks for some reason, or were in separate files wrapped in a closure.